# How to dynamically alternate columns between dataframe subset given column prefixes in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID <- c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0)
State <- c('AZ', 'IA', 'MN', 'NY', 'IL', 'FL', 'TX', 'TN', 'LA', 'ND')
ABC1_current <- c(1, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5)
ABC2_current <- c(4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2)
ABC1_future <- c(2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4)
ABC2_future <- c(2, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2)

df <- data.frame(ID, State, ABC1_current, ABC2_current, ABC1_future, ABC2_future)
```

I am trying to dynamically place the columns with the `future` suffix to the right of the columns with the `current` suffix for the given prefix (`ABC1`, `ABC2`, etc.) The `ID` and `State` columns don't move at all. Here's what I am hoping to get as a result:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID, State, ABC1_current, ABC1_future, ABC2_current, ABC2_future)
```

Is there a way to interlace columns like this dynamically? Ideally, I'd like to use `dplyr` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Although not purely dplyr, this may help.

This takes advantage of ordering logic by number value.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% select("ID","State") 
df2 <- df %>% select(-c("ID","State")) 
index <- sort(colnames(df2))
df3 <- merge(df1,df2[index])
df3

     ID State ABC1_current ABC1_future ABC2_current ABC2_future
1   1.1    AZ            1           2            4           2
2   1.2    IA            1           2            4           2
3   1.3    MN            1           2            4           2
4   1.4    NY            1           2            4           2
5   1.5    IL            1           2            4           2
6   1.6    FL            1           2            4           2
7   1.7    TX            1           2            4           2
8   1.8    TN            1           2            4           2
9   1.9    LA            1           2            4           2
10  2.0    ND            1           2            4           2
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same idea as @PeteKittinun's:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(ID, State, sort(colnames(.)[3:ncol(.)]))
```

returns

```r
> df %>%
+   select(ID, State, sort(colnames(.)[3:ncol(.)]))
    ID State ABC1_current ABC1_future ABC2_current ABC2_future
1  1.1    AZ            1           2            4           2
2  1.2    IA            5           5            5           5
3  1.3    MN            3           3            5           5
4  1.4    NY            4           5            4           1
5  1.5    IL            3           3            2           2
```